# How to import data from relative path for multiple documents?

Tags: paths, multiple-files

I have pgfplots tikzpicture where I use data from external data file. I use this picture in multiple latex documents that are located in different directories. So when I try to compile these documents, the relative path for data files is not always the same. Is there a way to import data that is relative to tikzpicture document instead of relative to working directory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can use the [`import`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import) package for this.

```
\import{path to folder}{filename}
```

Comment: I am not so sure this works for pgfplots. Let's say that I have main document in latex/main.tex and I use input to include tikzpicture from latex/plots/diagram.tex. In diagram.tex file I import data from data/dataForDiagram.dat file with pgfplots table command. I tried to import diagram.tex file with import and subimport commands but data won't be imported. It causes error: could not read table file '../../data/dataForDiagram.dat'